# Is there a way to determine a precise fraction from a large sample monte carlo simulation using R?

Tags: r

This past weekend I participated in the annual MIT Puzzle Hunt. [This puzzle](http://pennypark.fun/puzzle/food_court/) had 12 probability problems we had to solve. While we didn't complete it in time, I decided I wanted to try and solve it myself (so no spoilers).

Problem 8 currently has me tripped up. It states: *Alice got 16 coins from tips, and Bob got 3. They decide to play the following game. Each player chooses one of their own coins. They flip their coins until one is heads, the other is tails. The person with heads keeps both coins. This is repeated until one player gets all the coins. What is the probability that Alice loses her tips to Bob?*

I'm not great at statistics, and I'm sure there is a way to calculate this using a formula (any guidance here would also be appreciated), but I realized I could potentially calculate an answer by simulating the outcomes in R.

Here is the code I ran for the simulation (warning, im new to R so apologies the jankiness and bad formatting):

```
coin_battle <- function(alice_points,bob_points){
Alice <- alice_points
Bob <- bob_points
    while(Alice !=0 & Bob !=0){
        result <- sample(1:2,1)
        if(result == 1){
            Alice <- Alice + 1
            Bob <- Bob - 1
        }
        else{
            Alice <- Alice - 1
            Bob <- Bob + 1
        }
    }
if(Alice==0){
    return("Bob")
}
if(Bob==0){
    return("Alice")
}
}
simulate <- function(sample_size){
n <- sample_size
res <- rep(0,n)
    for(i in 1:n){
        res[i] <- coin_battle(16,3)
    }
    return(res)
}
vector1 <- simulate(10000)
table(vector1)
```

I just ran this code with a sample size of 10,000,000, and the results were that Alice would win the game 8,420,661 times, and Bob would win 1,579,339 times, so Bob will win 15.79339% of the time. I had a friend confirm that this decimal answer is correct. **However, for the purposes of the puzzle, the answer needs to be in the form of a fraction.** I suspect that both the numerator and denominator of the reduced form will be 26 or smaller, as the puzzle will probably have me translate the fraction into letters. I could probably guess and check the potential options using numbers between 1 and 26, but I would like to know if there is a more generalizable solution to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a direct way to estimate the exact fraction.  But you have a large simulation so you can put a confidence interval around the true probability.  From there you could make an assumption that the denominator is less than some arbitrary value and check all fractions that meet that criteria to see if they fall in the confidence interval.  I wrote some code to do that because this question intrigued me.  Be warned - this is extremely bad code as I'm kind of sick and not thinking very clearly.

```
ps <- prop.test(1579339,10000000)

# arbitrarily assume the denominator is <= 100
denominators <- 1:100
# numerators
num <- lapply(denominators, function(x){sequence(x)})
# the decimal values
vals <- lapply(denominators, function(x){sequence(x)/x})

# helper function to pluck the values that fall between the interval
between <- function(x, a, b){
  a <= x & x <= b
}

# find the values that fall in the interval
btw <- lapply(vals, between, a = ps$conf.int[1], b = ps$conf.int[2])
# not too proud of this.  it's ugly and there is a better way
output <- data.frame(percs = unlist(vals),
                     num = unlist(num), 
                     den = rep(denominators, denominators), 
                     between = unlist(btw))
# only grab the output that meets our criteria
possible <- output[output$between,]
possible
```

which gives us

```
> possible
         percs num den between
174  0.1578947   3  19    TRUE
709  0.1578947   6  38    TRUE
1605 0.1578947   9  57    TRUE
2862 0.1578947  12  76    TRUE
4480 0.1578947  15  95    TRUE
```

and all of those reduce down to 3/19.

Comment: I love the use of hypothesis testing to zero in on the fraction. Super clever! Now I just have to figure out how to understand this code